# Key Pressed event not firing when button is present on scene

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard-events

I'm creating a game with JavaFX that requires arrow key input. I need to get the event *when the key is pressed*, not when it's released.

However, when I add a button to the scene, for some bizarre reason it doesn't register the arrow keys. All of the other keys register, just not the arrow keys.

The problem *is* fixed when I set the event to key released, however, I need to get the event when the key is *pressed*.

I've tried switching focus to the root with requestFocus() and creating a separate root for the button and focusing the other root.
I've tried researching this, but all I could find was stuff about removing focus from buttons... I figured that was the case, but if it is then I haven't managed to remove focus from the button.

Here are some relevant snippets from my code:

```
Button reset = new Button("Reset");
reset.setLayoutX(defacto_width/2);
reset.setLayoutY(control_height/5);
reset.setOnAction(e -> {
    Map.generate();
});

control.getChildren().add(reset);
master.getChildren().addAll(control, content);
Scene scene = new Scene(master, defacto_width, defacto_height);
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    System.out.println(e.getCode().toString());
});
```

If it helps, I'm using the Pane() class for control, master, and content. Control just has 2D primitives, and content has the button, a label, and a rectangle.

Comment: Considering it’s a game, you might want to call `reset.setFocusTraversable(false);`.

Comment: Oh, that worked! Thanks!

Comment: I love you @VGR